# Why copies the values of an existing message (including its target) into the new one?

Tags: java

Why copy the attributes of an existing Message object (including its target) into the new one? what is the benefit?

```
/**
 * Same as {@link #obtain()}, but copies the values of an existing
 * message (including its target) into the new one.
 * @param orig Original message to copy.
 * @return A Message object from the global pool.
 */
public static Message obtain(Message orig) {
    Message m = obtain();
    m.what = orig.what;
    m.arg1 = orig.arg1;
    m.arg2 = orig.arg2;
    m.obj = orig.obj;
    m.replyTo = orig.replyTo;
    m.sendingUid = orig.sendingUid;
    if (orig.data != null) {
        m.data = new Bundle(orig.data);
    }
    m.target = orig.target;
    m.callback = orig.callback;

    return m;
}
```

Comment: This is similar to `clone`

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally familiar with the context but his method makes an another message object. One could have done it like this

```
Message m = orig;
```

but the problem with direct assignment is that it only creates a new reference of orig Message object. If i change anything like

```
orig.what = "test";
```

then m.what will also become "test" as both are pointing to same object.

So to preserve original data when we have to perform some modifications on existing object then one can use this method.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new object so you can change the original and not change the copy.  This is sometimes useful, if you need a second instance that's the same as/similar to the original.  With Messages for example you may want to add two copies of a Message to a handler so that it processes two messages, not just one.  This is actually such a common usage that its built into some languages-  in C++ they talk about copy constructors which do this.